# How can I reload a JS file every 10 seconds locally without a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have a local(no web server is used here) web page, and I wanted to read a file called sample.json which was also local to my machine.

After a lot of googling and reading about security holes and the way javascript is locked down, I eventually decided to just change contents of sample.json to have code as per the following in my json file:

```
var obj = {
"invoices":[
    {"open":"3","priority1":"2","priority2":"1","p1":"1400","p2":"1603","p1":"1301","p4":"1351"},
    {"supplier":"6","priority1":"3","priority2":"3"},
    {"client":"7","priority1":"3","priority2":"4"}
]
};
```

Now in my html I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="samples/sample.JSON"></script>
```

Now I want to re-read that file every 10 seconds, without refreshing the page, as the contents of that JSON object 'obj' is changing dynamically. I know this is all a bit of a hack but I cannot workout how to read a local json file any other way.

Comment: You can create ajax request to  this file.

Comment: Create an ajax function to retrieve the new data and then call it with a `setInterval()` method with 10 seconds of delay

Comment: .. and wrap it in `setInteval` or `setTimeout`

Comment: I don't think you can use Ajax for local files without disabling some security settings.

Comment: Depending on the browser, an AJAX call to a local file may fail.

Comment: What you've done is the completely *wrong* way of going about this, and you cannot make it work. There is no way to periodically reload a JavaScript file and have the contents of your variable `obj` magically change. You need to restore it to an actual JSON file, and periodically fetch the contents.

Comment: btw, your JSON code is not JSON but JavaScript

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Yes, read the question, he specifically addresses this. He had no idea how to fetch JSON data so he turned his JSON into JavaScript so he could just include it via a `<script>` tag.

Comment: This is polling the server for new data, not loading a new js file.

Comment: No its not - in this question there is **no** server. Please all commenters **read** the question.

Comment: In general it is a bad practice to run html with out run it from server. Init server on your computer. Their is "budo" server or another servers. npm install -g budo

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have to change your JSON file to contain JSON object.
if you want to see run

```
JSON.stringify(yourObject);
```

Create an ajax (this is a way if you use jquery)

```
function foo() {
  $.get("samples/sample.JSON", function(data) {
        // do something with data
        console.log(data);
  });
}

//every 10 sec the function call.
setInterval(foo, 10000);
```

You will receive the data from the file and use it as you want.

Comment: This does **not** work. Browser reports :  Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.send @ jquery.js:9664m.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:9215m.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:9361foo @ actions-chart.js:228

Comment: this is not cross origin. You have to start the web on server, and this is have to work.

Comment: In general it is a bad practice to run html with out run it from server. Init server on your computer. Their is "budo" server or another servers. npm install -g budo

Answer (score -3):

I would take a different approach, but it's more work.

Use Nginx (or your favorite web server) to create a local server for your samples.json file. Then you can use AJAX to get it at "http://localhost/samples/sample.json".

That way you don't have to side step any security settings and it will work with any browser.

Comment: With PHP installed cd to the web root and do: $ php -S localhost:1234 to start a server.

Comment: Thats answering my question though. The question details that no webserver can exist. How can i do this!

Comment: @RenegadeAndy Nowhere in your question does it state that a web server cannot exist. And really, 3 down votes?